Strapi CMS PUT for repeatable items or media via REST API
How do I update each asset or all assets via PUT rest API? If this is my document:
{
    "data": {
        "id": 5,
        "documentId": "bui11070zyexg20k1xg9fdxx",
        "name": "Test Document",
        "createdAt": "2024-12-13T05:52:18.359Z",
        "updatedAt": "2024-12-13T21:15:20.414Z",
        "publishedAt": "2024-12-13T21:15:20.966Z",
        "locale": "en",
        "assets": [
            {
                "id": 8,
                "documentId": "pku4d0m6e5x43ehr0f6o6ar7",
                "name": "142bdf157191583.63749e49bcb3a.jpg",
                "alternativeText": null,
                "caption": null,
                "width": 2048,
                "height": 2048,
                ...
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "documentId": "noz98h30ln5qatv7gc5nqhhp",
                "name": "27a5197bdaf301a49d1fa23eb2391256.png",
                "alternativeText": null,
                "caption": null,
                "width": 900,
                "height": 900,
                ...
            }
        ]
    },
    "meta": {}
}

How do I update each asset or all assets via PUT rest API?
I tried eg. this:
https://localhost/api/documents/bui11070zyexg20k1xg9fdxx
body(JSON)
{
    "data": 
        {
            "name": "Test Document Updated",
            "assets": [
                {
                    "caption": "Test 1"
                },
                {
                    "caption": "Test 2"
                }
            ]
                
        }
}

but get 400 Bad Request:
{
    "data": null,
    "error": {
        "status": 400,
        "name": "ValidationError",
        "message": "Invalid relations",
        "details": {
            "errors": [
                {
                    "path": [],
                    "message": "Invalid relations",
                    "name": "ValidationError"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

this works no problem:
{
    "data": 
        {
            "name": "Test Document Updated"
        }
}

if I PUT the entire assets array back with changed caption field, I get:
{
    "data": null,
    "error": {
        "status": 400,
        "name": "ValidationError",
        "message": "Invalid key documentId",
        "details": {
            "key": "documentId",
            "source": "body"
        }
    }
}

when I do this, I also get ValidationError:
{
    "data": {
        "id": 5,
        "documentId": "bui11070zyexg20k1xg9fdxx",
        "name": "Test Document",
        "createdAt": "2024-12-13T05:52:18.359Z",
        "updatedAt": "2024-12-13T21:15:20.414Z",
        "publishedAt": "2024-12-13T21:15:20.966Z",
        "locale": "en",
        "assets": [
            {
                "name": "142bdf157191583.63749e49bcb3a.jpg",
                "alternativeText": null,
                "caption": null,
                "width": 2048,
                "height": 2048,
                ...
            },
            {
                "name": "27a5197bdaf301a49d1fa23eb2391256.png",
                "alternativeText": null,
                "caption": null,
                "width": 900,
                "height": 900,
                ...
            }
        ]
    },
    "meta": {}
}


You need to remove id and documentId from components, you have to provide full array of components. You can do partial update via connect() disconnect()

Hi @antokhio. I tried:
{
"data":{
"scenario_name":"Test Container Scenario 2",
"assets":{
"connect":[
{
"documentId":"pku4d0m6e5x43ehr0f6o6ar7",
"caption":"Test 1"
},
{
"documentId":"noz98h30ln5qatv7gc5nqhhp",
"caption":"Test 2"
}
]
}
}
}
and get "ValidationError"

The same for sending the array of assets but without asset id & documentId

Ok, this kind of work I had to add id & documentId. I get response back, but the values are not getting updated: {
"data":{
"scenario_name":"Test Container Scenario 2",
"assets":{
"connect":[
{
"id": 8,
"documentId": "pku4d0m6e5x43ehr0f6o6ar7",
"alternativeText": "Test 1",
"caption": "Test 1"
},
{
"id": 7,
"documentId": "noz98h30ln5qatv7gc5nqhhp",
"alternativeText": "Test 2",
"caption": "Test 2"
}
]
}
}
}

Here you have better formatting: https://forum.strapi.io/t/put-for-repeatable-items-or-media-via-rest-api/49520

Components in strapi work that way, that they are recreated on every update, so you have to remove documentId and id. I strongly suggest start with providing whole array in there.

@antokhio I added your suggestion to the original description but also get ValidationError

could you please add schema.json files of related items. I likely know what the issue is, but need to recreate your setup to write u a proper answer.
